# How to create a keyboard shortcut to specific folders on desktop?

Tags: server, keyboard, directory, shortcuts, desktop-icons

I have installed Ubuntu 22.04 and I need to create keyboard shortcuts for folders on my desktop including "Home" folder. I tried creating shortcuts through Settings>Keyboard>Shortcuts. But it did not work. Anyone help me out.

Comment: First star any folder, then access it quickly by clicking on Starred in the left column.  Nevertheless it is not a shortcut.

Comment: do you mean that you want a shortcut that opens a file manager (ie Files) with the indicated folder open? Also, what exactly did you do in Settings>Keyboard>Shortcuts ?